# Where can I find a bitmap for the part of the DHT that my node stores on the hard drive

Tags: bitmap, ipfs, dht

So there must be some information that a node providing DHT support must store or the hard drive.

What exactly is stored?  For example, here is a [Here is a Bitmap for a bitcoin trasaction](https://en.bitcoin.it/w/images/en/e/e1/TxBinaryMap.png).  Is there something similar for the stored part of the DHT?